# iOS12 UICollectionView willDisplay cell called on all cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikeyboard

My keyboard extensions which consists of a `UICollectionView` of `UIImages` keeps crashesing on iOS12 after exceeding 53MB of RAM

`collectionView:willDisplay cell` is called on all cells, regardless if they are shown

NOTE: `didEndDisplaying` gets never called

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay c: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

can i bring back the behaviour of `collectionView:willDisplay` so its called only when the cell is really displayed?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: EmojiCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EmojiCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EmojiCollectionViewCell
    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay c: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = c as! EmojiCollectionViewCell

    let imageName = String(format:"%@-%@", categories[selectedCategory], NSNumber(value: indexPath.row + 1));
    let emojiImage = UIImage(named: imageName)

    cell.setupWithEmojiImage(image: emojiImage)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying c: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = c as! EmojiCollectionViewCell
    cell.setupWithEmojiImage(image: nil)

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code samples?

Comment: i provided the delegate method implementations

Comment: What's wrong to set the image in `cellForRow`? And you don't need to create an `NSNumber` instance. Use the specifier `%ld` and pass the `row` directly or use String Interpolation.

Comment: cellForRow is also called for all items in table

Comment: I mean `cellForItem`.

Comment: yes, cellForItem is called for all cells

Comment: and didEndDisplaying is never called, event the cell is scrolled out

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling reloadData() or something within a tableview datasource method, causing an infinite loop.  what is the code in `setupWithEmojiImage(image: nil)`?  I think you should place the following in cellForRow instead of willDisplay:

```
let imageName = String(format:"%@-%@", categories[selectedCategory], NSNumber(value: indexPath.row + 1));
let emojiImage = UIImage(named: imageName)
cell.setupWithEmojiImage(image: emojiImage)
```

Also avoid using the bang operator (!) to force unwrapping, this leads to crashing if the object doesn't exist.  Do this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell: EmojiCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EmojiCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? EmojiCollectionViewCell {
        return cell
    }
   
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```